# Substitute a function with the preprocessor

Tags: excel, build, preprocessor, project, codeblocks

I must do a *horrible thing*, i.e. automatically substitute a function call with a different function call, with different number of parameters, at precompilation time.
Example:

```c
#include <iostream>

int FuncToChange(void* a, int b, void* c, int d) {
   return 0;
}

int NewFunc(void* a, void* c, int d) {
   return 1;
}

#define FuncToChange($1, $2, $3, $4) NewFunc($1, $3, $4)

int main()
{
   int a = 1, b = 2, c = 256;

   int v = FuncToChange(&a + 1, c + 1, &b, 2*c);
}
```

This code works, i.e. in `main()` `NewFunc()` is called instead of `FuncToChange()`.

Now I would like to remove that #define (the reason is that **I cannot modify the code**), and obtain the same result setting the IDE's build options.

The IDE is **[CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org)** 10.05.

I already tried to add what follows to Project / Project Build Options / Compiler Settings / #define:

```
NewFunc($1, $3, $4)=FuncToChange($1, $2, $3, $4)
```

but nothing changed. Does anybody have any idea?

Thank you in advance!

*Pietro*

***Platform***:
GCC/MinGW
Windows7 64 bit

---

Reason behind this question:

I have to port an Excel plugin from XP 32 bit to Windows 7 64 bit. The plugin has been developed with CodeBlocks, and I cannot change tool set. The file FRAMEWRK.C (part of "2010 Office System Developer Resources", Excel2010 XLL SDK) has evolved, and now uses calls to non standard functions such as `memcpy_s()`, not available in MinGW. So, with the preprocessor, I substitute `memcpy_s()` with `memcpy()`, taking care of the different parameters.

Comment: can you explain your situation on why you feel you need to do something like this?

Comment: @VictorT.: I updated my question with an explanation of the reason behind it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I moved the `#define` in its own include file. Then I specified it to GCC, with the `-include` command line option.
Doing so, the file is included at the top of every source file.